# myeclipse maven build 206 error

Tags: maven, drools

> Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Failed to
> execute command line : Caused by:
> org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while
> executing process. Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
> "D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206,
> 文件名或扩展名太长。
> [image]

Comment: Far too little information about the problem, to warrant many people investigating it. Try searching for a solution.

Comment: First , I am sorry for my English,because I am chinese.

Comment: It is when I run maven commond  in myeclipse:-X clean install.And the error occured!

Comment: It has took me a long long time ,but I have no answer,please help me!

Comment: The literal meaning is about that the maven command is too long,so error

Comment: The project is drools-workbench.It locates "https://github.com/iamzken/kie-wb-distributions"

Comment: Try this search URL: https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=F2sUV4roJ6nS8Ae0zIHYCQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=cannot+run+program+createprocess+error%3D206+java and see if any of the hits helps you.

Comment: I searched much and nothing helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says 文件名或扩展名太长。 which translates to "The filename or extension is too long". Check the stack trace. It shows a long command line trying to be executed, but I can't see the whole line. So the problem may be exactly as stated in the error message and you will have to find a way to reduce the length of the command line, perhaps by reducing the length of the classpath parameter.

Comment: But it is a open-source project,how and why has so big error?